# Scrapy shell error how to fix it how to use this type of url

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, screen-scraping

Hi I am beginner in web scraping i just learning [scrapy](https://.scrapy.org/). When I try to use this type of url in scrapy shell its always show an error how to bypass it

```
scrapy shell https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=software+engineer&geo_location_terms=Glendale%2C+CA 
At line:1 char:79
+ ... ://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=software+engineer&geo_loca ...
+                                                                 ~
The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double quotation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmpersandNotAllowed
```

crapy code

```
import scrapy


class YellowSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'yellow'
    allowed_domains = ['yellowpages.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=software+engineer&geo_location_terms=Glendale%2C+CA']

    def parse(self, response):
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the url with quotation marks:

```
scrapy shell "https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=software+engineer&geo_location_terms=Glendale%2C+CA"
```